# SQL Server not reachable from ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sockets

I have an ASP.NET page which has a small form to handle enrollment into his course.

Obviously the data from this form has to be inserted into a database.

My problem lies in the actual connection to the database server, I have it on my local PC, for testing purposes.

I can connect to the server just fine through my SQL Server Management Studio, however when I try to connect from my web application (uploaded it to a free host purely for testing), it gives me this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.)

After extensive Google'ing and rewriting the connection string in my `web.config` file, I still can't find what's going wrong exactly.

I know for a fact that the DNS I'm using works, as a friend of mine has already tested it several days ago by connecting through his own SQL Server Management Studio.

Here's my `web.config`: (blanked out the password in the constring, obviously)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
      <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="SQLCS" 
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"   
          connectionString="Server=ydekempe.ddns.net,5555\Cocktails;Database=Website;Integrated Security=False;User ID=WebUser;Password=********;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And just for being complete in providing you everything you may need, here's the code for the actual connection:

```
protected void Inschrijven(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int uid = 0;
    string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLCS"].ConnectionString;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Inschrijven", conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam", txtNaam.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@voornaam", txtVoorNaam.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    uid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    string msg = "";
    switch (uid)
    {
        case 0:
            msg = "Er ging iets mis.\\nProbeer later opnieuw";
            break;
        case -1:
            msg = "Dit e-mail adres is al in gebruik.";
            break;
        default:
            msg = "Inschrijving verwerkt.";
            break;
    }
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Boodschap", "Boodschap: '" + msg + "');", true);
}
```

PS: The actual connection info is IP: ydekempe.ddns.net & Port: 5555
Just in case you were wondering.

Comment: [C# how to configure connectionstrings to databases](http://www.connectionstrings.com) I would start looking at the examples here.. also look at namedpipes just look at the working examples under SqlSever

Comment: Tried that, none of the examples there worked (after editing the IP etc. of course) Also, I presume as the error states `provider: TCP Provider` that the code is actually using TCP/IP & not Named Pipes

Comment: I just tried to connect via SSMS to ydekempe.ddns.net,5555\Cocktails specifying Integrated Security. It told be that *Login failed for user YORRICK\Gast *. So it seems that all the correct ports are open (although where it got the user from is perplexing!). It may be that the web host doesn't have port 5555 open for outgoing. I would check that next - unless they've said it is I would expect almost everything to be shut by default.

Comment: Can you run `Visual Studio` as Administrator and retry ? you can also run `netstat -o` to see which process use this socket.

Comment: @Ofiris I'm not testing the code with Visual Studio, the application is being run on a (temporary) webhost. I know for a fact that 5555 is the port being used by the SQL Server, unless somehow Windows managed to mess it up

Comment: @simonatrcl isn't Integrated Security the same as Windows Auth? If so, that should be disabled.

Comment: I agree with **simon at rcl** - `An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.` indicates that the port usage is being blocked by your web host.  This isn't an issue with the connection string; it's an issue with your free hosting.

Comment: @zimdanen Damn :| Any of you guys know where I can find a free webhost for testing purposes then? One with ASP.NET support obviously

Comment: Well I am able to access your server, but I think that only reason I cannot connect is that I do not know password. Seems to me it is working fine up to that point...

Comment: @Dusan I see, I'll have a go at sending in a ticket about the ports to the webhost then, hopefully the issue lies with them & not my code :)

Comment: You have tried connecting through Visual Studio *but with windows authentication* (which would never work). Please try to connect using VS but use SQL Sever Authentication, WebUser and his password and tell us what happens then. I mean, this is the absolutely first thing that you should try.

Comment: @Dusan I'm not actually testing the page through VS, I can log into my SQL Server perfectly fine using both the DNS and localhost as IP's, the only thing that's not working is the actual connection from webpage to my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database server is your local, and where is the Web server hosted? You mentioned it is a free host and I am guessing it is not on your local machine. Make sure your machine is accessible from wherever the web application is hosted. For instance, If its is in AWS, you have to verify both Inbound and Outbound rules.

Comment: In my OP: `I know for a fact that the DNS I'm using works, as a friend of mine has already tested it several days ago by connecting through his own SQL Server Management Studio.` So yes, it's actually accessible from the internet, as for the webhost, the page is being hosted on [SmarterASP](http://smarterasp.net) and I have no way of editing/seeing open/closed ports

Comment: and I was right. The oubound rules from your web server is blocking it. Glad you got it resolved.

Comment: Indeed you were, although I will say your answer was slightly more expansive, but still, more than enough to earn you the Accepted Answer :-) - also, the issue's not really resolved, basically I have no way of using my local DB with that host, unless I actually pay for their service, which I don't need/want.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it was the webhost blocking the outgoing port.

Reply from tech support at [SmarterASP](http://smarterasp.net):

> Dear Customer,
>
> Sorry, for performance reasons, we don't allow our customer to connect
>   to remote database server. We suggest you simply make a backup of your
>   database and restore it to our server to test your application. You’ll
>   see a much faster performance and reliability using this method.
>
> However, if you must connect to a remote database server, please
>   consider upgrading to our Premium Plan or Semi Dedi Plan. Once you
>   upgrade to these hosting plans, you can enable any ports your want in
>   your Control Panel -> Security Manager -> Outgoing Port Manager.
>
> And don't worry, we provide a 60 days FULL Money Back for all of our
>   plans.
>
> Thank you.